# Pointer to 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d, sudoku

I am trying to make a sudoku solver in C.
I have tried to make a function to solve the sudoku and then return the grid.

```
void solve(int *grid){
    //solve sudoku
}

int main(){
    int[][] grid = {
        {5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0},
        {6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0},
        {0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0},
        {8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3},
        {4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1},
        {7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6},
        {0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0},
        {0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5},
        {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9}
    };
solve(&grid);
}
```

This does not seem to work.
It needs to take a pointer because it should edit the array not a copy
Why is this?

Comment: what's about the `*` in `*solve(&grid);`?

Comment: A pointer is intentionally not called "array". Note that you cannot pass arrays to/from functions in C.

Comment: i thought that was to un-pointer it if that makes sense

Comment: Do return value is required? Also `int[][] grid` --> `int grid[][9]` or `int grid[9][9]`

Comment: no actually as the pointer is not changed

Comment: So `int* solve(int* grid){` --> `void solve(int grid[9][9]){`, `grid = *solve(&grid);` --> `solve(grid);`

Comment: this line: `int[][] grid = {`  should be: `int grid[][] = {`

Answer (score 0):

First of all this declaration of an array

```
int[][] grid = {
    {5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0},
    {6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0},
    {0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0},
    {8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3},
    {4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1},
    {7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6},
    {0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0},
    {0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5},
    {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9}
};
```

is wrong. You have to use square brakets after the identifier and specify at least the number of elements in the inner dimension.

```
#define N 9

//...
int grid[][N]  = {
    {5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0},
    {6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0},
    {0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0},
    {8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3},
    {4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1},
    {7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6},
    {0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0},
    {0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5},
    {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9}
};
```

If you want to pass the array to a function then the function can be declared like

```
void solve( int ( *grid )[N], size_t n );
```

and called like

```
solve( grid, N );
```

Take into account that arrays do not have the copy assignment operator and you may not assign an array identifier with a pointer.